# How to generate more than one key-value pairs for one input line in Hadoop Input Format?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Here is the background. I have the following input for my MapReduce job (example):

```
Apache Hadoop
Apache Lucene
StackOverflow
....
```

(Actually each line represents a user query. Not important here.) And I want my `RecordReader` class read one line and then pass several key-value pairs to mappers. For example, if `RecordReader` gets `Apache Hadoop`, then I want it to generate the following key-value pairs and pass it to mappers:

```
Apache Hadoop - 1
Apache Hadoop - 2
Apache Hadoop - 3
```

("-" is the separator here.) And I found `RecordReader` pass key-values in `next()` method:

```
next(key, value);
```

Every time a RecordReader.next() is called, only one key and one value will be passed as argument. So how should I get my work done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can simply use this:

```
public static class MultiMapper 
        extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) 
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            context.write(value, new IntWritable(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Here n is the number of values you want to pass. For example for the key-value pairs you specified:

```
Apache Hadoop - 1
Apache Hadoop - 2
Apache Hadoop - 3
```

n would be 3.

Comment: You mean I doing this job in the first Map Phase? But the values would be collected together in the next Reducer. What I want is sending the key-value pairs to different mappers. For example, "Apache Hadoop - 1" to Mapper 1, "Apache Hadoop - 2" to Mapper 2, just like this.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? To speed things up? Can you please explain what you have in mind?

Comment: Alright then. Please accept the answer if it is what you were expecting. That way if someone encounters the same problem in future, (s)he will know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to send to the mapper use the same key; you must implement your owner RecordReader;  for example you can wirte a MutliRecordReader to extends the LineRecordReade; and here you must change the nextKeyValue method;
this is the original Code from LineRecordReade：

```
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException {
    if (key == null) {
      key = new LongWritable();
    }
    key.set(pos);
    if (value == null) {
      value = new Text();
    }
    int newSize = 0;
    // We always read one extra line, which lies outside the upper
    // split limit i.e. (end - 1)
    while (getFilePosition() <= end) {
      newSize = in.readLine(value, maxLineLength,
          Math.max(maxBytesToConsume(pos), maxLineLength));
      pos += newSize;
      if (newSize < maxLineLength) {
        break;
      }

      // line too long. try again
      LOG.info("Skipped line of size " + newSize + " at pos " + 
               (pos - newSize));
    }
    if (newSize == 0) {
      key = null;
      value = null;
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

and you can change it like this:

```
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException {
    if (key == null) {
      key = new Text();
    }
    key.set(pos);
    if (value == null) {
      value = new Text();
    }
    int newSize = 0;

    while (getFilePosition() <= end && n<=3) {
      newSize = in.readLine(key, maxLineLength,
          Math.max(maxBytesToConsume(pos), maxLineLength));//change value --> key

     value =Text(n);
     n++;
     if(n ==3 )// we don't go to next until the N is three;
         pos += newSize;

      if (newSize < maxLineLength) {
        break;
      }

      // line too long. try again
      LOG.info("Skipped line of size " + newSize + " at pos " + 
               (pos - newSize));
    }
    if (newSize == 0) {
      key = null;
      value = null;
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

I think this can suit for you

Comment: I doubt this. You assign “value” three values, but can the three values all be sent the mapper? Or just the third value be sent to the mapper?

Comment: the split can only handle by one mapper; one splitter one mapper

Comment: one split may equal one block in hdfs, handled by only one mapper;  and one split can generate many keyvalues; these keyvalues all handled by one mapper,so you cannot send the same split keyvalues to different mappers;

Comment: Yes. I realized this. I made a mistake just now.

Answer (score 0):

Try not giving key:-

```
context.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text("Apache Hadoop - 1"));
context.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text("Apache Hadoop - 2"));
context.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text("Apache Hadoop - 3"));
```

Comment: I hope to do this in RecordReader, but not Mapper.